# Is it possible to use value of first MySQL select as condition in second when autocommit is off?

Tags: php, mysql, select, autocommit

First of all, I'm still Learning how to work with PHP/MySQL... so is it possible at all to use transactions when selecting or only when inserting/updating?

If it is possible, then how would I solve this (pseudo-code):

Turn off autocommit

Select id from auth where alias = [user input]

Select active from flags where id = ID FROM ABOVE SELECT

If: no errors
Commit

Else:
Rollback

Fetch row from second select

---

Is the above possible to do with MySQL (PHP syntax, please)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using transactions would be rather useless here, since your query only deals with a `SELECT`.

There are 2 choices here. (Do note that I've only included the SQL-code.)

**1. You can use a `SELECT` inside a `SELECT` statement.**

```
SELECT active
  FROM flags
 WHERE id IN (
               SELECT id
                 FROM auth
                WHERE alias = 'userinput'
             );
```

**2. Other possibility is to use a `JOIN`.**

```
    SELECT f.active
      FROM flags f
INNER JOIN auth a
        ON f.id = a.id
     WHERE a.alias = 'userinput';
```

Here, aliases like `f` and `a` are used to designate the tables.

Comment: Went with the select in select solution and it worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot!